# Como podría crear un documento txt y añadirle texto con saltos de línea?

Tags: javascript, html

Por ejemplo: Hola que tal

y lo que quiero que escriba en el documento txt:

```
Hola
que
tal
```

/* Corregido */

```
var data = "Hola, \r\n ¿qué \r\n tal?";

var filename = "example_text.txt";
var type = "text/plain;charset=utf-8";

var a = document.createElement("a"),
    file = new Blob([data], {type: type});

if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) { // IE10+
    window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(file, filename);
} else { // Others
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    a.href = url;
    a.download = filename;

    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.body.removeChild(a);
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    }, 0);
}
```

---

Dándole seguimiento a las respuestas recibidas:
He probado lo que me has dicho pero sigue poniéndomelo en la misma línea

/* Corregio */

```
var data = "Hola";

data += "\r\n"; // salto de linea
data += "que";
data += "\r\n"; // salto de linea
data += "tal";

var filename = "net_view_cmd.txt";
var type = "text/plain;charset=utf-8";


        var a = document.createElement("a"),
                    file = new Blob([data], {type: type});
                if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) // IE10+
                    window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(file, filename);
                else { // Others
                    var url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                    a.href = url;
                    a.download = filename;
                    document.body.appendChild(a);
                    a.click();
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        document.body.removeChild(a);
                        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);  
                    }, 0); 
         }
```

Comment: ya intentaste poner `"\r\n"` en lugar de `"\n"`?

Comment: Si, ya está corregido y funciona perfectamente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hace un tiempo tambien me sucedio ese problema con salto de lineas en Unix lo resolvi con `\r\n` probe en Windows y siguio funcionando. Reemplaza en tu código en `\n` por `\r\n`, quedando asi:

```js
var data = "Hola";

data += "\r\n"; // salto de linea
data += "que";
data += "\r\n"; // salto de linea
data += "tal";
```

.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, ya me funciona, agradezco tu ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Añade `\n` donde quieras el salto...
Ej.

```
var data = "linea_1\nlinea_2\nlinea_3";
```

Para tu ejemplo:

```
var data  = "Hola";
    data += "\n"; // salto de linea
    data += "que";
    data += "\n"; // salto de linea
    data += "tal";
```

Comment: No entiendo, pero no me funciona :-(